# Simple Present / Formal Future use in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, tense

This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171032/regarding-present-tense-and-future-tense) on ELU asked

> In this sentence "Look at the timetable. Hurry up! Flight 4026 takes off at 6:20." Can I replace "will take off" with "takes off"？

A user commented on the question like this

> They do not mean the same. The Simple Present Tense (Present Indefinite) is used for something that happens regularly/ usually/ normally -- Flight 4026 (generally) takes off at 6:20 . On the other hand, the formal future tense *will*+verb indicates a (definite) possibility in the future

and I asked that user this question

> Are you saying that it would be incorrect to say The plane takes off at 6:20 in the case where that route and timing had never been flown before and will never be flown again by that plane ?

They kindly directed me to ELL for an answer, so here I am asking the question

**Is it incorrect to say *The plane takes off at 6:20* in the case where that route and timing had never been flown before and will never be flown again by that plane?**

Comment: It could be a lot easier for you if you think of English tenses as a two-tense system (past and non-past), and *will* as just a modal verb (to express a possibility in the future). For what it's worth, I agree with njboot's answer there.

Comment: @Damkerng As a life long (very long) native speaker I don't have a grasp of all these Simple Present/ Formal Future tense definitions as I didn't have to _learn_ them; I just _know_ what words to use. However, I'm not above learning something new (or finding out that something I thought was correct is in fact wrong). The sentence in question seems perfectly fine to me but being unaware of the intricacies of the tense terminology I thought I'd better check.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought you were the OP of the original question there! I read that comment again, and I think what you were really arguing was about that "regularly/ usually/ normally" part, right? Imo, I think it's fair to say that *"regularly, usually, normally"* covers things such as timetables. So I read that comment as "they do not mean the same", but that doesn't mean that either of them can't be used in the example sentence, and it implies "it's fine to say *The plane takes off at 6:20* in the case you gave".

Comment: @DamkerngT. No problem and thanks for the further confirmation that _The plane takes off at 6:20_ does not depend on it being a repetitive or normal event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether it has ever flown before or it's only flying one time.

The simple present can be used for something that is happening for sure (irrespective of the *number of times* it has happened in the past or will happen in the future).

See these -

> The movie **starts** in 10 minutes - Talking about **the movie** which is starting in a few minutes. It could be for a movie that has never been shown before i.e. this is the first show. Nor am I talking about the future shows of the movie.

In the same way,

> The train *departs* in 10 minutes, hurry - I am concerned about the event that is happening **for sure** in the future.

So, **you can say** that whether the flight happens to be for the first time or for the last time.